# Laravel 4.1 - Can developers add their own config files to my package?

Tags: php, laravel, package, config

The package I have developed comes with a set of config files. However I want other devs to be able to add their own, not just configure the default ones.

However, now that I have tried publishing my package to packagist and installing it as a vendor package via composer, it seems that Laravel will ignore config files unless the same file name existed in the original vendor package! This is true even if I explicitly do

```
 Config::get('{package-name}::{file-name}')
```

Only if that file name exists in the original workbench package does Laravel seem to allow devs to access it.

Comment: After installing the package are you running `php artisan config:publish vendor/package`? It should publish it in `app/config/packages` and people will be able to edit/add configurations.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro oh I did that. I just want my package users to be able to add more config files. When they try to add them and call Config::get('{package-name}::{file-name}'), laravel does not load the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this with namespaces for my package config:

```
Config::addNamespace('package', __DIR__.'/path/to/config');
```

See here for info: http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration